# How do I assign a custom ID to a dynamically generated URL with Iron Router in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

How do I have the URL of a dynamically generated post be one of the attributes assigned to it? Say it's name? So instead of events/vbMmmw6ymrWXjtXPd the URL is events/name-of-the-event

Here's my routing so far:

```
    Router.route('/events/:_id', {
      name: 'event',
      data: function() { return Events.findOne(this.params._id);}
    });
```

And my schema:

```
Events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
Events.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Name",
    max: 200
  },
  crew: {
    type: String,
    label: "Crew"
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    label: "Location"
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Date"
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    label: "Wha'appening?",
    max: 1000
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add uniq slug in your schema (based on name) like:

```
Events.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  slug: { //example: my-name-slug
    type: String
  },
 (...)
}));
```

And then in your Router:

```
Router.route('/events/:slug', {
  name: 'event',
  data: function() { return Events.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a way you know of I can sanitize the slug based on the name within the schema? Or should I do that somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with something like:

```
var makeSlug = function (str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-');
    str = str.replace(/^-|-$/g, '');
    return str;
}

Events.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  slug: { //example: my-name-slug
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return makeSlug(this.field('name'));
        } else if (this.isUpsert) {
            return {$setOnInsert: makeSlug(this.field('name'))};
        } else {
            this.unset();
        }
    }
  },
 (...)
}));
```

Be careful, this is not tested ;) Remember that slug shouldn't update if you update the name. This is blocked here.